# When to use ebenso instead of auch?

Tags: colloquial

Are *ebenso* and *auch* frequently interchangeable?  Or are there nuances to their meaning I should be aware of, especially as to which word is preferred by modern German natives in their speech?

For example:

*Musik ist für mich sehr persönlich*

Would one reply with:

"Ja, sie ist für mich auch persönlich."

Or:

"Ja, sie ist ebenso für mich persönlich."

Also, is the use of both of them in the same sentence considered redundant?

For example:

"Ja, sie ist ebenso für mich auch persönlich."

Comment: _Er_ in conjunction with _Musik_ is wrong.

Comment: Haribo macht Kinder froh und Erwachsene auch.

Answer (score 3):

**Auch** is additive. **Ebenso** is comparative.

So you can say

> Für mich (ist Musik) auch (sehr persönlich).

But you can't compare the quality or quantity of *persönlich*.

> Ich mag A und auch B.

I like both A and B.

> Ich mag A und ich mag B ebenso.

I like A and B equally.

Answer (score 2):

**Auch** and **ebenso** are synonyms.

*Also, is the use of both of them in the same sentence considered redundant?*

- Yes it would be redundant.

If you use **ebenso** it's like you're talking about one thing and the other thing is as important as the first thing.

```
In einer Beziehung ist Treue wichtig, ebenso das Vertrauen zueinander.
```

If you use **auch** it's more like a side note

```
Liebe ist wichtig, Geld aber auch.
```

Comment: Eben so auch gehört: Nutzen sie 'ebenso' auch so oft? Oder ist das 'auch' ebenso überflüssig? Redundanzen sind nicht schlecht, sondern ebenso *auch* ganz nützlich.

Comment: "auch" and "ebenso" are not complete synonyms: *Ich gehe ebenso gerne ins Theater wie ins Kino* - you can't replace "ebenso" with "auch" here.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf You could say: `Ich gehen gerne ins Kino und auch ins Theater`. And that is like I said: *If you use ebenso it's like you're talking about one thing and the other thing is as important as the first thing.*

Comment: I think you are missing the comparative aspect of _ebenso_.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot use **ebenso** in this context, so:

```
Ja, er ist für mich auch persönlich
```

is the correct one.
**ebenso** meaning is **equally**. For example:

```
Eine ausgewogene Ernährung ist gesund, aber Bewegung ist ebenso wichtig.
```